# Change menu-link class to active on a one-page website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a one-page website for a sort of portfolio. On this site, I have a menu on the top with links that just puts the visitor on a selected part of the page using # as links.

I want it to make it so if you're at the  (the top of the site) the "home" link changes css class to a.menuActive which changes the color of the menubutton. So it changes when you click it or just simply scroll to that section. Same with the other links. How can I do this? Probably need a sort of script sensing where the user is on the page.

Comment: `:active` should be enough.

Comment: Apologies, I ment `:target`

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question correctly. :active just starts if you're holding the mouse-button on the object. Once you release it's back to normal

Comment: But that won't really sense if I'm on it's position on the page? Tried it and it did nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuerys .scroll() method.

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    // access the current vertical position of the scrollbar with .scrollTop()
    if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
        // scrolled to top of page --> change home link css 
    }
});
```

you can use jquery by inserting a script tag that links to the jQuery file (must be before you use jQuery in your javascript). you can either use [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) or [download jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and put into your project.

You can change the class like this (i havent seen your code so you would have to change one or the other thing)

```
// remove class 'active' from all elements with class 'fake-link'
$('.fake-link').removeClass('active');

// add class 'active' of the element with id 'fake-link-home'
$('#fake-link-home').addClass('active');
```

To change other links than the home link, you can maybe try something like  this:

```
if($(document).scrollTop() > 50 && $(document).scrollTop() < 200){
    // change class of some link
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200 && $(document).scrollTop() < 400){
    // change class of other link
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: So without any needed knowledge of jquery, how do I use this? Also how to make it change the class on links in the middle of the page etc?

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/
This is my site: http://jonathan.ohrstrom.nu might be easier for you to check the source than me pasting all the code xd

Comment: you can give your <li> 's a class, lets say 'nav-link'. also you give them each a separate id like 'hem', 'info' and so on. After that you can get the elements easily with jQuery: get elements with class: $('.classname') get element with id $('#idname'). Im sorry i cant help you further i have to go now.. but i guess you can get familiar with jQuery by googling some stuff